# 2 drop down menus w/o submit button

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

I would like to know how to submit two drop down menus w/o a submit button. I want to populate the second drop down menu on selection of the first and then be able to echo out the selection of the second drop down menu. Data for the second drop down menu is obtained from a mySQL database. I am using two forms on my page, one for each drop down menu.

```
    <form method="post" id="typeForm" name="typeForm" action="">
          <select name="filterType" onchange="document.getElementById('typeForm').submit()">
                   <option <?php if ($_POST['filterType'] == 'none') print 'selected '; ?> value="none">Filter by...</option>
                   <option <?php if ($_POST['filterType'] == 'employee') print 'selected '; ?> value="employee">Employee</option>
                   <option <?php if ($_POST['filterType'] == 'taskName') print 'selected '; ?> value="taskName">Task</option>
          </select>
          <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></noscript>
    </form>
    <form method="post" id="categoryForm" name="typeForm" action="">
          <select name="filterCategory" onchange="document.getElementById('categoryForm').submit()">
                    <option <?php if ($_POST['filterCategory'] == 'none') print 'selected '; ?> value="none"></option>
                    <?
                        $count2 = 0;
                        echo $rowsAffected2;
                        while ($count2<$rowsAffected2) {
                             echo "<option value='$filterName[$count2]'>$filterName[$count2]</option>";
                             $count2 = $count2 + 1;
                        }
                     ?>
           </select>
           <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></noscript>
     </form>
```

I can submit the first form with no problem. It retrieves values into the second drop down menu successfully.But on selecting a value from the second menu the page refreshes and I'm left with an two unselected drop down menus. I tried echoing the $_POST['filterCategory'] and didn't get a result. I tried using onchange="this.form.submit();" in both forms and I still get the same result. Is there a way to do this without using AJAX, JQuery or any complex Javascript script? I require to this completely in PHP.

I want to avoid the second refresh but still be able to gather the $_POST[''] data from the second selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the same form for both selects

Comment: Okay, but I require the post value from both forms. How to obtain that then? What I do is, I check the posted value of the first drop down menu and populate the second drop down based on that value from a mySQL database. And hope to echo out the data selected from the second drop down menu.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It worked, but just need a few more tweaks to make it perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways of doing that. 
You can either submit the form using **AJAX**; that will prevent the whole page from refreshing, and hence, losing the data in both select elements; that is also the coolest way to have it done.
**OR** 
Using a single form, when both the first and second select elements are submitted, use their values to re-create the select elements. 
The cleaner way to do it is still the first option; at least, that's what I'll use if I have to do it.

Comment: I had asked this at a time when an AJAX call was like studying another language for me. I might have been a couple of days into PHP. Plus I had asked to do it without using AJAX, JQuery or any complex Javascript script. But yes, AJAX is the right way to go in any other case.

Comment: Nice that  you are a PHP ninja now :-). If my answer makes sense, give it a rating. :-)